# To find equation between two columns

Tags: algorithm

I have a table as
 **Input**

```
A B 
3 20
5 30
6 35
```

I need an algorithm to find out the formula(Equation) associated with the two columns A and B

**Output**

```
B=(A+1)*5
```

Comment: That formula doesn't work for the first row...

Comment: the question is the algorithm to find relationship between two columns..i.e., For an I/P table .. I need algorithm to compute(find out) the formula as O/P

Answer (score 1):

One relatively simple approach would be to use least squares curve fitting for a variety of families of curves (say polynomials up to degree n-2, exponentials, power laws) and look for the one with minimal residual.  This would give you approximate formulas (unless you only accepted the curve with zero residual), but perhaps that's okay for your application?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming the formula you want is a polynomial.**

What we know? For a list of A values, we have their B values. With "n" A values, the best polynomial we can find is of (n-1)th degree. Why?

Basically I'm solving a linear system like the following:

```
x + Ay + (A^2)z = B
```

With the example:

```
x + 3y + 9z = 20
x + 5y + 25z = 30
x + 6y + 35z = 35
```

After solving this, we can find that (x, y, z) = (5, 5, 0). This means that our polynomial is 5 + 5A + 0(A^2), that is basically the same B = (A+1)*5 you showed in the example.

We can solve the system using any method. Don't know if it will help, but I'll throw some code here to solve it with Gaussian elimination (in Python):

```
def solve(A, B):
    n = len(A)
    M = [[a**i for i in range(n)]+[b] for a,b in zip(A,B)]

    for i in range(n):
        M[i] = [x / M[i][i] for x in M[i]]

        for j in range(n):
            if j==i: continue
            M[j] = [xj - xi * M[j][i] for xi, xj in zip(M[i], M[j])]

    return [M[i][-1] for i in range(n)]

print solve([3,5,6], [20, 30, 35])
```

Answer (score -1):

If formula is first order linear like in example then you are looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

or this for higher order linear equations

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Comment: Oh yea. I thought linear means first order. my bad. thanks. fixed answer